# Create a JSX list column from every level of multi-level nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I want to turn nested object into multi level column. where every column represents a level in the nested object. I also need to keep the original nested object intact for state management.

sample nested Object

```
[
  {
    "id": "1.1",
    "displayLabel": "level 1.1",
    "selected": true,
    "options": [
      {
        "id": "2.1",
        "displayLabel": "level 2.1",
        "selected": true,
        "options": [
          {
            "id": "3.1",
            "displayLabel": "level 3.1",
            "selected": true,
            "options": []
          },
          {
            "id": "3.2",
            "displayLabel": "level 3.2",
            "selected": true,
            "options": []
          },
          {
            "id": "3.3",
            "displayLabel": "level 3.3",
            "selected": true,
            "options": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2.2",
        "displayLabel": "level 2.2",
        "selected": true,
        "options": [
          {
            "id": "3.4",
            "displayLabel": "level 3.4",
            "selected": true,
            "options": []
          },
          {
            "id": "3.5",
            "displayLabel": "level 3.5",
            "selected": true,
            "options": []
          },
          {
            "id": "3.6",
            "displayLabel": "level 3.6",
            "selected": true,
            "options": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "1.2",
    "displayLabel": "level 1.2",
    "selected": false,
    "options": [
      {
        "id": "2.3",
        "displayLabel": "level 2.3",
        "selected": false,
        "options": [
          {
            "id": "3.7",
            "displayLabel": "level 3.7",
            "selected": false,
            "options": []
          },
          {
            "id": "3.8",
            "displayLabel": "level 3.8",
            "selected": false,
            "options": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

//i am trying recursive rendering but it create new column for every nested object.

```
  const levels = [];
    const PrintLevels = ({ hierarchy }) => {
      const list =[];
      hierarchy.forEach( level => {
        list.push(<li className=`${level.selected ? 'bold': ''}`>{level.displayLabel}</li>)
        if(level.options.length > 0 ) {
            PrintLevels( { hierarchy: level.options })
        }
        levels.push(<ul>{list}</ul>)
     })
     return levels;
    }
```

current output

| First Level | Second Level | Third Level | Forth Level | Fifth Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Level 1.1** | **Level 2.1** | **Level 3.1** | Level 1.2. | Level 2.2 |
|  | . | **Level 3.2** | . | . |
|  |  | **Level 3.3** | . | . |

so on..

expected Output

| First Level | Second Level | Third Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Level 1.1** | **Level 2.1** | **Level 3.1** |
| Level 1.2 | **Level 2.2** | **Level 3.2** |
|  | Level 2.3 | **Level 3.3** |
|  |  | **Level 3.4** |
|  |  | **Level 3.5** |
|  |  | **Level 3.6** |
|  |  | Level 3.7 |
|  |  | **Level 3.8** |

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), show what you have tried and what isn't working, and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt when possible.

Comment: @pilchard added code for what i have tried. please up the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const parseLevels = ( levelIndex, hierarchy, hierarchyLevels ) => {
    hierarchy.forEach( level => {
        const { id, displayLabel, selected, options } = level;
        if( !hierarchyLevels[ levelIndex ] ) {
            hierarchyLevels[ levelIndex ] = [ {id, displayLabel, selected} ];
        }else {
            hierarchyLevels[ levelIndex ] = [ ...hierarchyLevels[ levelIndex ], {id, displayLabel, selected} ];
        }
        if ( options.length ) {
            parseLevels( levelIndex + 1, options, hierarchyLevels );
        }
    } );
};


const PrintLevel = ( { level } ) => {
    return level.map( ( {selected, displayLabel} ) => <li className={`${selected ? 'bold': ''}`}>{displayLabel}</li> );
};
  
const PrintLevels = ( { levels } ) => {
return levels.map( ( level ) => <ul>
    <PrintLevel level={level} />
</ul> );
};

const hierarchyLevels = [];
parseLevels( 0, hierarchy, hierarchyLevels );

// render
<PrintLevels levels={hierarchyLevels} />
```